# SetUniqueList, HashSet and Set don't remove duplicates from a List of an object

Tags: java

What I've been trying to do is to sort objects in a List and remove duplicate objects from the same List.

Here is the class of the object

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{

private String wordName;
private int number;

 // There are only simple constructers, getters and setters 

 // This compareTo might be irrelevant for this question
@Override
public int compareTo(Word word) {
    int compareNumber = ((Word) word).getNumber();
    return compareNumber - this.number;

    }
}
```

Here is part of the main method

```
public class CommentEvaluationTester {
 final static private List<String> WordsList = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean isContained;
    String comment = "";
    //This "comment" actually has a long string value
        for (String word : WordsInDB) {
        //WordsInDB is a List, containing String values

        isContained = comment.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase());
        if (isContained) {
            WordsList.add(word);
        }
    }

     List WordsListWithNumber = new ArrayList<>();

     for (String word : WordsList) {
            int occurrences = Collections.frequency(WordsList, word);

            Word addWord = new Word(word, occurrences);
            WordsListWithNumber.add(addWord);

     }

     //This might be irrelevant too   
     Collections.sort(WordsListWithNumber, new Comparator<Word>() {
            @Override
           public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
                return w2.getNumber() - w1.getNumber();
            }
        });
```

At this stage, "WordsListWithNumber" list contains several instances of "Word", and I've been trying to eliminate duplicates from this List.

I have found several ways on Stackoverflow.

1. SetUniqueList

   ```
   List<Word> NoDup = SetUniqueList.setUniqueList(WordsListWithNumber);
   ```
2. HashSet

   ```
   HashSet hs = new HashSet();
       hs.addAll(WordsListWithNumber);
       WordsListWithNumber.clear();
       WordsListWithNumber.addAll(hs);
   ```
3. Set

   ```
   Set<Word> noDupSet = new LinkedHashSet<Word>(WordsListWithNumber);
      List<Word> noDup = new ArrayList<>();
      noDup.addAll(noDupSet);
   ```

I've confirmed that all those methods can remove duplicates from a List of "String", but it didn't seem to remove duplicates from a List of this class.

I checked the contents of the list by doing like this...but both of them show the same value.

```
    Word testWord = (Word) noDup.get(0);
    System.out.println("test1: noDup.get(0) : " + testWord.getWordName() + " , number : " + testWord.getNumber());
    testWord = (Word) noDup.get(1);
    System.out.println("test2: noDup.get(1) : " + testWord.getWordName() + " , number : " + testWord.getNumber());
```

I'd appreciate if you would give any insight.

**P.S.**

I realized that the "number" property should have been named "quantity"... It seems that some people think this "number" property is something like ID numbers, but it actually indicates how many the same word the "WordsList" contains.

I would like to compare the "wordname", not "number".
Sorry for confusing, I'm not an native English speaker.

Comment: Wait; how do you determine "duplicates"? Is that on the result of `Comparable` or `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`?

Comment: Why does your `Comparable` only check the `number`?

Comment: The trouble is we don't know whether there's supposed to be any link between `wordName` and `number`. Subtraction-based comparators don't meet the contract for `compareTo` anyway because the subtraction can overflow.

Comment: >fge, any option is fine as long as duplicates are removed. I used "Comparable" in order to sort the "WordsListWithNumber" list by the "number" property. (i.e. I'd like to sort the list so that the first word has the largest "number" property) To be honest, I'm not familiar with .equals()/.hashCode() yet. I used SetUniqueList, HashSet and Set, just because they were frequently shown on Stackoverflow.

Comment: >Elliott, I used Comparable in order to sort the "WordsListWithNumber" list, since I'd like the first "Word" in the list to have the largest "number" property. I didn't use it for removing duplicates... Can Comparable be used to remove duplicates?

Comment: >pbabcdefp, do you mean that the "compareTo" method has to deal with both "wordName" and "number" ? To be honest, I used "compareTo" and "Collections.sort" by just referring to other postings, and I have not 100% understood the algorithm of them yet.

Comment: There's a lot of rubbish on this site - I've generated a lot of it. No, I mean that subtraction can give the wrong result. If `a` is 0 and `b` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the mathematical result of`a - b` is too big to fit in an `int`, so the answer overflows and you get a negative int. Therfore your `compareTo` method says that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is bigger than 0. This may not be a problem if `a` and `b` will always be close to 0. We can't tell from your example because we don't know what `number` means. The correct way to write a comparator for `ints` is `return Integer.compare(a, b);`.

Comment: I fixed the "Word" class and it now works properly. Thank you all for your kindness. I think I have learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicates from a `List`, you need to specify when you consider two items to be duplicates. It is important to specify because in your case there are at least 4 possible interpretations for what it means for `word1` and `word2` to be duplicates:

1. `word1 == word2`.
2. `word1.number == word2.number`
3. `word1.wordName.equals(word2.wordName)`
4. `word1.number == word2.number && word1.wordName.equals(word2.wordName)`

You have indicated that you mean 3.

The way you specify what you mean by duplicates is by overriding the `equals` method. You can do that as follows.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    return object instanceof Word && ((Word) object).wordName.equals(wordName);
}
```

Whenever you override the `equals` method you must also override `hashCode`. (Search SO for the explanation for this).

Here is a possible `hashCode` method for `Word`.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return wordName.hashCode(); 
}
```

If you do this you will find that if `list` is a `List<Word>`, you can remove duplicates by writing

```
list = new ArrayList<Word>(new LinkedHashSet<Word>(list));
```

For full details on how to write `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` methods (your `compareTo` method can fail if the numbers are large), I recommend the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much... now it works as I wanted! I'll check the book too.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :). You MUST get that book. I learned everything I know about Java from that book.